# What are medical drugs?

Tags: meaning

The German word for "drugs" is (normally) only used for recreational drugs (mainly illegal ones).

In English "drugs" also refers to medically used substances. But does it only refer to psychoactive ones like opioid pain killers or is it also used for other kinds like antibiotics?

Comment: Well, given that "drugstore" is a very normal name for a pharmacy, I'd say all kinds.

Comment: Context usually make it obvious which sense is intended, but ***medication*** and ***intoxicants***, for example, are available to disambiguate the two likely referents.

Comment: @MrLister Interistingly, the German equivalent of "drugstore" means something like convenience store and is not related to pharmacies at all (although dict.cc translates it as "drugstore" or "pharmacy" which is plain wrong)...

Comment: What did your English dictionary tell you about the meaning of *drugs*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Mosby's Medical Dictionary:

***[Drug](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/drug):***

> - 1) ***also called medicine,***  any substance taken by mouth; injected into a muscle, the skin, a blood vessel, or a cavity of the body; or applied topically to treat or prevent a disease or condition.
> - 2 (informal) ***any substance that can be abused*** for its stimulant, depressant, euphoric, or hallucinogenic effects.

Note that  [drug addict](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/drug-addict) refers to:

> a person who is addicted to a narcotic.

(Dictionary.com)

[Drug](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=drug) original sense was that of medicine since the Middle Ages. It was applied also to "narcotics" much later, in the late 19th century:

> - ***late 14c. (early 14c. in Anglo-French), "medicine, chemical ingredients,"*** from Old French droge "supply, stock, provision" (14c.).
> - ***Application to "narcotics and opiates" is late 19c.*** , though association with "poisons" is 1500s.

(Etymonline)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [**pharmaceuticals**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pharmaceutical)

> A compound manufactured for use as a medicinal drug.

These would be "drugs" that available at a pharmacy. They can be over-the-counter or prescription medications.